# Location of jar file in application bundle mac os x

Tags: java, macos, jar

I'm trying to get location of jar file in .app bundle.
In Windows family I'm just typing something like this

```java
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

But it's return incorrect result for mac os x family.

What's promlem?

P.s. I see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/936738/1808979, but I need location of jar, not of class.

Comment: That's not what `user.dir` does anyway. Since your main class will in fact be inside the JAR you're looking for, the answer you linked to will give you the location of both, you just need to parse it out of the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (`this` is an instance of my "main" class)

```
URL url = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
File f;
try
{
  // Send the URL through the URLDecoder to remove potential 
  // spaces that are encoded as %20 in the URL
  String p = URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(), "UTF-8");
  f = new File(p);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  // cannot happen
}
return f;
```